# One parameter file for different repositories Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: file, parameters, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a parameter file which is assigning DB Connections for one repository which stands for test. It is referring to the folder where the workflow and session is like the following.

```
[ORANGE_REMIGRATION.WF:wf_m_remigration_payments_test.ST:s_m_remigration_payments_test]
```

I would like to know whether I can use one parameter file to assign DB Connections for different environments e.g. when the repository is PROD then the workflow should write in that environment. I need to know whether we can use repository names in the parameter file e.g.

```
[MDM_TEST.ORANGE_REMIGRATION.WF:wf_m_remigration_payments_test.ST:s_m_remigration_payments_test]
```

whereas MDM_TEST would be the repository and then list the DB Connections and then another list in the same parameter file for MDM_PROD. Is this possible or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [description of Parameter File sections](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-2/advanced-workflow-guide/parameter-files/parameter-file-structure/parameter-file-sections.html). Repository is not allowed.

However if you migrate workflows between environments and use different Integration Service, there are different values for `$$ParamFileDir` (or `$$PMRootDir` in general). So if you refer to your file using the variable, migrated workflow will use the parameterfile for the given environment. Hence DEV WF would use DEV connections, PROD one would use PROD connections. No actions needed. More can be found [here](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/data-services/10-2/application-service-guide/powercenter-integration-service/powercenter-integration-service-processes/directories-for-powercenter-integration-service-files/configuring--pmrootdir.html).

Comment: Ok so that would mean I would still need a different param file for each repository right?

Comment: Yes - and that would be the best practice to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, your have distinct physical servers for DEV & PROD. If you define folder structure mirror each other like

```
/share/param/Paramfile1   ===> Dev server

/share/param/Paramfile1   =====> Prod Server
```

you can use the same param file. These param files can be configured via respective workflow properties.

Comment: Actually we solved the issue by using the built in parameter $PMRepositoryServiceName and we added to the parameter file names the endings of each resposity service name. That works quite well.